Establishing Wi-Fi connection to a PoE NVR in the attic
My client's Dahua PoE NVR is in the attic directly above her bedroom which is next to the garage, and her router is in the garage connected to the NBN box. I would like to connect her NVR in the attic to the Internet. I can think of two ways to do this:

Drill a hole in the ceiling, then run a long Ethernet cable from the NVR through the attic and down the hole in the ceiling to the router.
Install a Wi-Fi extender in the attic to extend the Wi-Fi network of the router to the attic and connect the NVR to the extender using an Ethernet cable.

Method 1 will be difficult and will cost my client an additional $100 in labour fee. Method 2 will cost less labour fee and be much easier, but I worry that the Wi-Fi signal in the attic will be too weak. Could you please recommend me the best solution?

This is a networking question not a home improvement question.

I’m voting to close this question because it's not about DIY Home Improvement.

Not my money, but I really recommend wired. Why? Because if:

Someone changes the Wi-Fi access details to prevent a previous user from being able to use the network
The WiFi source (router or otherwise) is replaced and left with default credentials
External factors cause more interference (which often leads eventually to replacement)

then the NVR loses access.
In general, when practical go for wired instead of wireless for any unattended headless (no keyboard / monitor) devices. Your future self will thank you. This applies to cameras, printers, alarms, etc.

Do not answer blatantly off-topic/opinion based questions. Answers interfere with proper automatic cleanup.
